# Using raspberry pi for 5 different frequency generation and FFT concurrently

Tags: hardware

I want to use a single raspberry pi to do the following concurrently -

1. Create 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 hz frequencies from 5 different ports.
2. Determine Fast Fourier Transforms of this 5 frequencies
   Can this be done? If yes please provide any information you know. It would be really helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you generate pure sine wave, then you do not need run FFT

Comment: I didn't understand. I need the FFT to determine the amplitude and discriminate 5 different frequencies. Are you suggesting any other method? Can you please explain. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you did not say anything about the waveforms that you are generating ... if you generate pure sine waveforms, then there are no harmonics ... the only components would be those five frequencies and you would not have to perform FFT because you already know what the frequencies are and their amplitudes